# Show multiple variables according to filter in mysql

Tags: mysql, mariadb

In `mysql`/`mariadb`, I can show variables using `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'pattern'`, is it possible to show multiple variables at one time:

```
SHOW VARIABLES like  'port';
SHOW VARIABLES like  'sql_mode';
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `where`

```
SHOW VARIABLES WHERE 
Variable_Name LIKE 'port' OR 
Variable_Name LIKE 'sql_mode'
```

Answer (score 10):

Here is another alternative, with less typing and more compact display of results by using '\G instead of ';' as the query terminator:

```
SHOW VARIABLES
WHERE Variable_Name IN ('port', 'sql_mode')\G
```